# Why use a buffer in/output for a RAM memory?

Tags: memory, ram, buffer

I was reading about the architeture of a RAM memory but now I'm confused about the use of buffer for input and output. Why I need to use this?

[image]

Comment: The buffers are internal to the RAM package. That diagram is not suggesting adding your own buffers. Also, please give a links to any resources you show, so that we can have a look at them too.

Comment: Buffers are good for two reasons, they can be used to synchronize all the data lines and they can be used for level shifting. As Andrew said, they are internal, the buffers translate (and probably amplify) the tiny signals coming from the teensy ram cells into something that can actually drive the logic of whatever the ram is connected to. Just because it might be 3.3V on the outside, doesn't mean it's all 3.3V on the inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data lines are used for more than one RAM module, so it it necessary to transfer data to/from the storage cells only when appropriate, hence the presence of chip select inputs to the buffers.

Voltage level translation is likely necessary, another function of the buffers.

The data to/from the storage cells may not all arrive at precisely the same time, so the buffers allow for some settling time, in conjunction with the output enable signal.

The write enable signal prevents data being written instead of read.